# UserEntitlements with oAuth token credentials

Tags: ajax, tfs, azure-devops

I am getting User Entitlements using oAuth token credentials, but getting error: **TF400813: The user 'userguid' is not authorized to access this resource.** Here is my code:

```
 var getUserEntitlements = function (access_token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://{myuseraccount}.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements/{userguid}?api-version=4.1-preview.1',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var b = "Bearer "+access_token;

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", b);
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        var d = data.response;
    }).error(function (e) {

    });
}
```

The question is either user is allowed to read users licenses using oAuth access token or not? How can I read user entitlements with oAuth?

Comment: Have you granted Entitlements scope for your oAuth token?

Comment: "vso.entitlements" is this the scope you are asking me to grant? If yes, let me try this at my end. Thanks

Comment: @Arsalan Younus, It seems that your previous issue has been resolved, am I right? If so, you could mark helpful solution as the answer. Of course, if you get any other VSTS issue, you could post a new thread with VSTS tags,we will follow up it in time.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried on my side, it is allowed to read users licenses using oAuth access token. You have to grant `vso.entitlements` and `vso.memberentitlementmanagement` scopes for your oAuth token.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dong, I got the solution.

Comment: Dong, Can you please tell me why isn't oAuth doesn't work with TFS also? I am using TFS 2018 Update 2 and getting this error: "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

Comment: I could reproduce your error on my side. I'm afraid this api doesn't support on-premise TFS.

Comment: So you mean to say it is not supported at on-premise TFS?

Comment: Hi Dong, I am having an issue with VSTS also, with Azure devops actually. Getting an error: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com